# Android text widget that generates a random value every second

Tags: android, text, random, widget

I'm new in the programming world, i'm in the dark now and for exercise
i should make a widget that shows random values ​​every second (by updating each value every time).
There is some good soul who could help me?
thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use thread to generate random numbers for every seconds.
use this function `final Random rand = new Random();`

Answer (score 0):

For the "every Second" Task you need a Scheduled Timer. and for the "Random Value" Part you can use the ''Math'' package. Then you can do something like this:

```
final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);        
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        textview.setText(Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt()));

    }
};      
Timer t = new Timer();
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, null, 1000L);
```

This is just quite messy. Use it as a example and please don't copy/paste it